# Is is possible to generate both 32 bit and 64 bit Installers for JavaFX using INNO Setup 5 with one build script?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, javafx-8

Currently our users are working on a mixture of 32 bit & 64 bit Windows 7 machines.  The goals is to get to a 64 bit for all users.

However in the mean time I need to build my application twice, remembering to switch the JDK out before executing the Ant Script making it pretty manual, and more challenging for a CI type build environment.

Is it possible to have a single build.xml which bundles and builds both versions of the application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far i know you need to use `Flags: 32bit` If you need that file to be install only in 32 bit and `Flags: 64bit` for 64 bit in `[Files]` Section in inno setup. If you want to install both system then don't use any 32,64 bit flag and it will install in both system.And don't forget to remove`Wow6432Node`part from registry,if you want to install in both system.